# How to import one databricks notebook into another?

Tags: python, python-import, azure-databricks, spark-notebook

I have a python notebook A in Azure Databricks having import statement as below:

```
import xyz, datetime, ...
```

I have another notebook xyz being imported in notebook A as shown in above code. 
When I run notebook A, it throws the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named xyz
```

Both notebooks are in the same workspace directory. Can anyone help in resolving this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only way to import notebooks is by using the run command:

```
%run /Shared/MyNotebook
```

or relative path:

```
%run ./MyNotebook
```

More details: https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html

Comment: Thanks Simon, is this still the best way to import modules/functions from other notebooks into databricks?

Answer (score 2):

To get the result back as a DataFrame from different notebook in Databricks we can do as below.

**noebook1**

```py
def func1(arg):

    df=df.transfomationlogic
    return df
```

**notbook2**

```py
%run path-of-notebook1

df=func1(**dfinput**)
```

Here the **dfinput** is a df you are passing and you will get the
transformed df back from func1.

Comment: This trick works with Databricks. The unique problem is that the functions defined in the runned notebook are red underlined as not defined...